# Creating a bucket in a particular region in Alibaba Cloud OSS using OSS Utility tool?

Tags: alibaba-cloud

How can I create a bucket in a particular region in Alibaba Cloud OSS Using OSS Utility tool? As far as exploring the official documentation I am not able to find anything related to specifying a region in the creation of a bucket using OSS Utility tool.

As per the documentation, The syntax for Creating a bucket is

```
ossutil mb oss://bucket [--acl=acl] [--storage-class sc] [-c file]
```

Here how can we specify the region? Please help me out with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The region is specified in the .ossutilconfig file.

- [Credentials]
- language=EN
- accessKeySecret=XXX
- stsToken=
- endpoint=oss-eu-central-1.aliyuncs.com
- accessKeyID=XXX

If you want to create bucket in the different region than configured in config file you can specify endpoint in command line.

> ossutil mb oss://stackbucketcn -e oss-cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com
>   --acl=public-read-write

You can find the list of OSS endpoints here https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/31837.htm